# Missing Library JWT Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jwt

Hi Im trying to use JWT in Spring boot

My code:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("user")
    public User login(@RequestParam("user") String username, @RequestParam("password") String pwd) {

        String token = getJWTToken(username);
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setToken(token);
        return user;

    }
```

and i added on dependencies:
[image]

But when i tried to run:
[image]

Show an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me worked just this way

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

without specifying compile or whatever time

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the project using

Select Build->Rebuild Project

might solve the issue.